Power Automate flow trigger issue - "Cannot use the changeToken.."
Power Automate flow with trigger <When a file is created or modified (properties only)> on SharePoint library with different folder and doc-set content types.
Had it running for some time and now it throws an error after save.
Cannot use the changeToken from one object against a different object.
clientRequestId: e3db713e-4f75-4071-a87e-6dfa92587598
serviceRequestId: e3db713e-4f75-4071-a87e-6dfa92587598

Unclear what the issue is - there isn't much to change in trigger it self.
Things tried:

delete trigger, add new (and fix all lost references :/ )
turn off / on
delete library, create again
in trigger settings - turn off and on "Split On" property

What is this error about? Why it pops up and how to avoid it?

Sounds like this is a bug in Power Automate. The changeToken is SharePoint-side but as your error message shows the Ids are identical between the client and the service. I recommend reporting it via the Power Automate Help -> Feedback menu option.

Oh I did not knew about "internal error, because Ids are identical" - well, it is quite evident that root cause is either user (me) or system.. and I cannot change anything on my side. Thanks for new info!
